# Restricting FlipsideViewController Orientation

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4.4

I am creating a simple utility app based on the xcode Utility App template. I want to restrict the FlipsideViewController orientation to only the orientation that the device was in when the  FlipsideViewController was called. What is the easiest way to do this? I've tried doing it several different ways but so far all of them have failed. Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get the current orientation:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear: (BOOL) animated
{
    eLockOrient = self.interfaceOrientation;
}
```

Then, disallow anything else:

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation
{
    if (eLockOrient == 0)
        return true;
    return (interfaceOrientation == eLockOrient);
}
```

**ADD**: I did some more testing and there are significant behavioral differences between the simulator and the device with respect to startup orientation.  The device appears to behave correctly, but the simulator does not.  It appears that if you put the simulator in landscape mode, when the app is started the simulator doesn't remember to send the app messages to tell the app that it needs to rotate.  The simulator doesn't realize that it is in landscape.  Below are traces from sim and device.

Device:

**[TiAeManageSearchesVC.shouldAutorotate] intfOrient=1
[TiAeManageSearchesVC.shouldAutorotate] intfOrient=1
[TiAeManageSearchesVC.shouldAutorotate] intfOrient=1
[TiAeManageSearchesVC.shouldAutorotate] intfOrient=4
[TiAeManageSearchesVC.shouldAutorotate] intfOrient=4
[TiAeManageSearchesVC.viewDidAppear] self.intfOrient=4**

Simulator:

**[TiAeManageSearchesVC.shouldAutorotate] intfOrient=1
[TiAeManageSearchesVC.shouldAutorotate] intfOrient=1
[TiAeManageSearchesVC.shouldAutorotate] intfOrient=1
[TiAeManageSearchesVC.viewDidAppear] self.intfOrient=1**

So the above code will work with the exception of the noted log message.  I am adding the following lines to improve the solution on physical devices.  This will eliminate the error message in the log.

```
if (eLockOrient == 0)
    return true;
```

Otherwise, I think the problem is with the simulator.  If you are trying to test against the first view when the app loads on the simulator, you will have these problems.  I have tested subsequent views and they work correctly if you do the following:

1. start the app.
2. rotate the simulator.
3. proceed to second view.

Comment: It locks the orientation down to just the single orientation now, but it gives me the following warning: "The view controller <FlipsideViewController: 0xae60e50> returned NO from -shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: for all interface orientations. It should support at least one orientation." By returning the orientation that was established when the view appeared how is that not supporting at least 1 orientation? I get this in the iPhone simulator...

Comment: Did you initialize `eLockOrient` before the first call to `shouldAutorotate...`?

Comment: It gets initialized when the view appears: - (void) viewDidAppear: (BOOL) animated
{  ...but maybe viewDidAppear doesn't always get called before shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation.

Comment: Got it working! I had to let the 1st pass through shouldAutorotate occur and return true, but before returning true I set the orientation of my orientation lock variable to self.interfaceOrientation. Then I nested all of this inside 2 if statements to check whether my orientation variable I just set to self.interfaceOrientation was greater than zero. If it was then I returned the current orientation. This resulted in a view that once initially opened would not be allowed to rotate.